# array column is returned as as string instead of array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have array column in the **pgsql db**, when i select the **column**

```
SELECT scopes FROM users
```

it Returns data like this `'{"admin","agent"}'` instead of `["admin","agent"]`.

Is there a way to do this.

I expect it to be `["admin","agent"]` and not `'{"admin","agent"}'`

Comment: It is an array. Postgresql uses this notation for an array literal. Do you want a json, jsonb or json-like string instead?

Comment: Well, [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) `'{"admin","agent"}'` is the output format of a "native" Postgres array - `["admin","agent"]` would be a JSON array

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it matches the common PostgreSql syntax for arrays, ex. a column can also be defined as an array to introduce another dimension.

Example input

```
INSERT INTO sal_emp
    VALUES ('Bill',
    '{10000, 10000, 10000, 10000}',
    '{{"meeting", "lunch"}, {"training", "presentation"}}');

INSERT INTO sal_emp
    VALUES ('Carol',
    '{20000, 25000, 25000, 25000}',
    '{{"breakfast", "consulting"}, {"meeting", "lunch"}}');
```

Becomes

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp;
 name  |      pay_by_quarter       |                 schedule
-------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------
 Bill  | {10000,10000,10000,10000} | {{meeting,lunch},{training,presentation}}
 Carol | {20000,25000,25000,25000} | {{breakfast,consulting},{meeting,lunch}}
(2 rows)
```

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html

> Is there a way to do this.

If the output isn't for ingestion by PostgreSql, then String substitution is an option.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('<your input>', '{', '['), '}', ']') ..;
```